# Can I send/transfer data from Smart Contract to an EOA?

Tags: solidity, eoa

I am quite new to the world of Ethereum and I'd like to know if it was possible to send or transfer data (not only ether) to a given EOA address. Thanks in advance. Best

Comment: Can you give an example of the data you want to send? For example, are you simply trying to add some metadata to a transaction?

Comment: I mean put in the field "input data" some information I want to be available from the whole chain (e.g., I want to store on the blockchain the String "I am a fun of the football team XYZ" in such a way that everybody can access or see this info)

Comment: It sounds like something that is not currently possible with regular solidity, but probably doable with [solidity assembly](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/assembly.html). However, practically speaking, I would question again what you really want to do here, and if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: I need to use this method "web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: src, to: dst, value: 0, data: "0x1234"})" by a smart contract where: from is an EOA eth address, dst is another EOA eth address and the data is a generic String (like the above one).

Comment: Thanks. The difference w.r.t. the referred question is that, in my case, the sender is not a user, but a contract: that is, a contract should generate the transaction with the data field. In that question/answer, it is not clear this point.

Comment: Look at the second answer posted by user eth. He addresses that

Answer (score 0):

I was reading [here](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/06transactions.asciidoc#transmitting-a-data-payload-to-an-eoa-or-contract) that the wallet containing the EOA should accept incoming data, apparently not all of them do, you should also check that.

I've never written an example like that so I can't help you there, normally you send data the other way around like explained in the link of the Ethereum Book. Maybe it helps